# How to return a value from an async function which also awaits for a value

Tags: flutter, dart, asynchronous, async-await

I am new to Flutter and the Dart programming language. I am making a shift-assignment app, but am stuck on this - I need to return a string from an async function which also waits for a value from other async functions. This is what I have written so far:

```
Future<String> getNumberOfShiftsText() async {
    int weekShiftCount = 0;
    List<DateTime> shiftTimes = [];
    await getUserDetailsFromServer().then((value){
      await getAppointmentsFromServer(cid, isEmployer, rolesList).then((aValue) {
        List<HiveAppointment> appointmentList = appointmentBox.values.toList();
        for (int i = 0; i < appointmentList.length; i++) {
          if (appointmentList[i].startTime.isBefore(DateTime.now().add(const Duration(days: 7)))) {
            weekShiftCount += 1;
            shiftTimes.add(appointmentList[i].startTime);
          }
        }
      });
    });
    return Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 1), () => '$weekShiftCount shift(s) assigned to you in the next 7 days',);
  }
```

On running this, I get the error:

> A non-null value must be returned since the return type 'String' doesn't allow null.
> Future getNumberOfShiftsText() async {

Any ideas on how I can solve this? Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks in advance, and I apologize for my lack of knowledge.

Comment: Just a general advice. Don't mix this usage of `await` and `then()` calls. It makes the code very hard to understand and the code are not going to be executed as you are probably expecting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not really sure about the core issue of your problem. But your code does contain a problematic pattern with mixing `then()` and `await` which can make your program run in an unexpected way.

I suggest rewrite your code into something like this:

```dart
Future<String> getNumberOfShiftsText() async {
  int weekShiftCount = 0;
  List<DateTime> shiftTimes = [];
  final value = await getUserDetailsFromServer();
  final aValue = await getAppointmentsFromServer(cid, isEmployer, rolesList);

  List<HiveAppointment> appointmentList = appointmentBox.values.toList();
  for (int i = 0; i < appointmentList.length; i++) {
    if (appointmentList[i]
        .startTime
        .isBefore(DateTime.now().add(const Duration(days: 7)))) {
      weekShiftCount += 1;
      shiftTimes.add(appointmentList[i].startTime);
    }
  }

  return '$weekShiftCount shift(s) assigned to you in the next 7 days';
}
```

I am not sure about your `value` variable since you are not using it in your code. Also the "wait 1 second before returning" has been removed since I think you added this because you did not know when the async code was done.

The rewritten code fixes this so when the `return` statement are executed, we know the other code are done being executed.

If you still have issues, can you provide a stacktrace combined with the full error so I know where the issue might be.

Comment: Thank you so much for your response. This indeed fixed my problem. I was unsure if the cursor would pass on and skip the functions where I put "await", hence my thinking of using then. Cheers

Answer (score 1):

#### General suggestion

Avoid `then` whenever you can. Always prefer `await`.

#### Explanations

`await` makes so that dart stays at that line waiting for the function answer so you can do:

```dart
Future<int> func() async {
  return 0;
}

int i = await func();
```

`then` also returns a `Future` which is the value you return inside its *lambda* or *tearOff*. But its idea is so that you can process asynchronous things inside a synchronous function. Means that whenever the future process gets done, it will start working on the `then` function, it will run "at the same time" (kinda) as the overlaying function (as I understand it, but you can always look for [Decoding Flutter playlist on Youtube](https://youtube.com/playlist?list=PLjxrf2q8roU1fRV40Ec8200rX6OuQkmnl) for trying to understand all this background processes better).

Comment: I see. Thank you for your response. I will keep this in mind going ahead.